# Execute cURL from Jenkins

Tags: windows, curl, jenkins, command-line

I'm trying to execute a cURL command from a Jenkins job. Basically I'm trying to retrieve JIRA information using cURL to JIRA REST API and then parse the information using jq.

I already have a working bat file when ran in command but when call it from the jenkins job I get a *'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command* error even though I can call cURL in any directory since I added it on my Window PATH.

I tried copying cURL.exe and jq-win64.exe in my Jenkins workspace and don't get any error but the execution doesn't retrieve anything but it does when ran in command prompt.

Anyone has any idea of what might be the issue? Below is my code:

```
SET jiraURL="http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/issue/%1"
SET contentType="Content-Type: application/json"
SET changeSetField=".fields.customfield_10000"
SET devSBField=".fields.customfield_10100"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%x IN ('curl -u admin:admin -X GET -H %contentType% %jiraURL% ^| jq-win64 %changeSetField%') DO SET changeSetName=%%x
ECHO %changeSetName%
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%y IN ('curl -u admin:admin -X GET -H %contentType% %jiraURL% ^| jq-win64 %devSBField%') DO SET sandboxName=%%y
ECHO %sandboxName%
```

Note: I know its not efficient to do 2 service call, but will deal with it once I'm done with this error. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like its a machine thing after all. I rebooted my machine, ran my local instance of JIRA via command line and then a couple of Java popups asking me about firewall.

After I set it up I executed my jenkins build again and to my surprise it was able to connect and retrieve the information I needed. i also didn't need to copy cURL.exe and jq-win64.exe to my workspace folder.